# JScrollPane does not work on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have a frame that contains a mainPanel. This last will add other commandPanels (each one contains a button and a textField) Dynamically. the problem is that the JScrollPane does not appear to let me use the unseen commandPanels even if the mainPanel is full.
The below picture shows my case.

[image]

To initialize the window I wrote below code:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 962, 639);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null); 

mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setBounds(264, 6, 692, 500);
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));    

scroll = new JScrollPane();
scroll.getViewport().add(mainPanel);
frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

and the method that add dynamically the new commandPanels is:

```
public void loadCommandPanel(String commandName)
{
    CommandPanel newCommandPanel = new CommandPanel();
    newCommandPanel.getCommandBtn().setText(commandName);   
    mainPanel.add(newCommandPanel);

    scroll.getViewport().add( newCommandPanel );
    mainPanel.add( scroll, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add( mainPanel);

    ...
}
```

Any help to get the scrollPane, will be much more than appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding the user of `null` layouts and the `setBounds` method. Try that and see if it works out. Also, why are you adding the panel to the viewport, instead of using `scroll = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);`?

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *"(each one contains a button and a textField)"* Consider instead using a `JList` to hold instances an object that has a `label` and a `command` attribute.  Use a rendererer to show the `label` in a `JLabel` and the `command` in a `JTextField`..

Comment: Or use a `JList` or `JTable`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes and it works perfectly now. For those who want the same thing here's my code:

```
import ...

public class mainUserInterface {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private  JPanel commandsPanel;
private JScrollPane commandsScrollPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mainUserInterface window = new mainUserInterface();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public mainUserInterface() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame("CommandsExecutor");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));

    mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
    mainPanel.setBorder( new TitledBorder("") );


    commandsPanel = new JPanel();
    commandsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(commandsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    for(int i=0; i<15;i++){

        commandsPanel.add(new CommandPanel());
    }

    commandsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(commandsPanel);
    mainPanel.add(commandsScrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and Here's the commandPanel class:

```
import ...
public class CommandPanel extends JPanel {

private JTextField commandResult;
private JButton commandBtn;

public CommandPanel()
{
    this.setLayout( new BorderLayout(10,10));
    this.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Command:") );
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(692,60));
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(692,60));


    commandBtn = new JButton("Execute");
    commandBtn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(137, 34));
    commandBtn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(137, 34));
    this.add(commandBtn, BorderLayout.WEST);

    commandResult = new JTextField();
    commandResult.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(518, 34));
    commandResult.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(518, 34));
    this.add(commandResult, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public JTextField getCommandResult() {
    return commandResult;
}

public JButton getCommandBtn() {
    return commandBtn;
}

public void setCommandResult(JTextField commandResult) {
    this.commandResult = commandResult;
}

public void setCommandBtn(JButton commandBtn) {
    this.commandBtn = commandBtn;
}
}
```

Thanks for all who answered my question, it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

`scroll.getViewport().add(mainPanel);` is not how you use `JViewport` or `JScrollPane`; instead you should using something like this:
    scroll.getViewport().setView(newCommandPanel);

or

```
scroll.setViewportView(newCommandPanel);
```

Take a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details.

Note also, this doesn't makes sense:

```
CommandPanel newCommandPanel = new CommandPanel();
newCommandPanel.getCommandBtn().setText(commandName);   
mainPanel.add(newCommandPanel);

scroll.getViewport().add( newCommandPanel );
```

You add `newCommandPanel` to `mainPanel`, then promptly add it to another container (albeit incorrectly).

A component can only reside on a single parent; the moment you add it to another container, it is automatically removed from the previous container.